# CListView filtering by value

Tags: yii, clistview

is there a parameter that I can use with ClistView to get the commments of a given post_id

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_comment',
    'template'=>"{items}\n{pager}",
)); ?>
```

I'd like to add post_id =  value  in order to only list the comment with the given post_id

I put a search function in my comment model

```
public function search()
    {
        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('post_id',$this->post_id,true);

        return new CActiveDataProvider('Comment', array(
            'criteria'=>$criteria,
            'sort'=>array(
                'defaultOrder'=>'status, create_time DESC',
            ),
        ));
    }
```

Thank in advance for your help.  I cannot find in the documentation.

Comment: Post your controller code.

Comment: Well, you should simply modify your data provider, show us your code...

Comment: I updated the post with the search function in my model @kumar_v

Comment: I'm looking in my controller , I think  I'll find  thank you all

Comment: So you found solution?